# Swiper JS Do not slide on transition start

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm using swiper.js library and want to change the behaviour on a slider.
The default effect is "slide", which means an image slides from right to left. However, I would like to disable this behaviour in a callback function I wrote after the initialization of my slider. Is there any way I can approach this so that the inactive slide fades out and the active on slides in?

```
let swiper = new Swiper(element, settings);

        swiper.on('slideChangeTransitionStart', () => {
          $('.swiper-slide').each(function () {
            if ($(this).index() === swiper.activeIndex) {
              // Slide in active slide, enable slide behaviour
              console.log('slide in');
            } else {
              // Fadeout inactive slide, enable fade effect
              console.log('fade out');
            }
          });
        })
```

Comment: did you manage to solve it?